# war file works in Eclipse, but doesnt in Tomcat

Tags: веб-программирование, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, tomcat

Я разрабатываю простейшее приложение SPring Boot в Eclipse. Проект в роджном Eclipse на Tomcat запускается хорошо и работает, но как только я сгенерированный war файл переношу на отдельный tomcat, он хорошо разворачивается но при запуске возникает ошибка 404.

мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lakecomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>vegem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>vegem</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

мой main class:

```
package com.lakecomp.vegem;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;



@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"controllers"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class VegemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VegemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

мой servletinitializer:

```
package com.lakecomp.vegem;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(VegemApplication.class);
    }

}
```

my controller:

```
package Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Заглавие");
        return "main";
    }
    
}
```

и мой main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   
</head>
<body>

Hello!!!
 
</body>
```

в eclipse:[image: in eclipse]

в tomcat:
[image: tomcatmanager]

и:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прошу помощи!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Понял, извиняюсь, уже перевел))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему так и не решил, но выход нашел. В случае небольшого проекта я просто переустаовил Tomcat, создал новый проект с помощью start.spring, указав там War packaging и все заработало.